# Error 400: invalid_request when using Google Oauth 2.0 in local

Tags: angular, google-api-js-client

Authorization Error
Error 400: invalid_request

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.

You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.

[image]

What I've tried so far:

- Add a custom domain in the host file so I can go to the website using something like mywebsite.com:4200. Same error
- Make localhost HTTPS using self-signed certificates, google says the domain is not a valid origin even though I already added https://localhost:4200 in the console.

The OAuth works fine when in the test and production environment, the problem is I cannot test the application in my local machine. This only happened this month, last month this was intermittent and a refresh would fix the issue.

If it helps, I am using ng-gapi. Here's my config:

```
import { NgGapiClientConfig } from 'ng-gapi/config/GoogleApiConfig';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';

export const gapiClientConfig: NgGapiClientConfig = {
  client_id: environment.clientId,
  discoveryDocs: [],
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
};
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue, I have the same issue

Comment: Yes, I created a separate google project and set the publishing status to testing.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail, did that work for you?  The publishing status for  my project was already at testing

Comment: me too i have same issue and my project is already at testing

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, create a new google project and set the publishing status to testing.

[image]

Comment: my app is published and it has more than 100 users, so testing app doesn't work